# How to create a "Goal Seek" using SciPy's functions

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, newtons-method

I have been struggling with this for a long time now and i hope that someone can help me. I have a function named "ULS" which looks something like this

```
def uls(muliple, known, values):
# result = (a value calculated by the known values and the unknown x0)
return result
```

The function contain multiple equations which depends on the known values plus one unknown value x0. The sum of all these equations should be zero (Target) and i want to know for which x0 value my target can be met. (Kinda like a goal seek). Currently i have all this in a loop and i am running through many x0 values until a condition is met. Can Scipy method be used here ?

The equations are linear.

More info. Im looking at this specific problem. For a chosen value of x_bot all the lists and variable are calculated and the expression abs(equN - N) is evaluated. Now i want to find the value of x_bot which makes the abs(equN-N) < 1.

def ULS(xp_bot):

```
    xp_top = 0.00014                    
    xp_all = []            
    slope = (xp_bot-xp_top)/(Ln)            

    for i in range(0,100,1):
        xp_calc = i*slope + xp_top 
        xp_all.append(xp_calc)
    xp_all.append(xp_bot)

    xmi_all = []          
    for i in range(0,100,1):
        xmi_calc = (xp_all[i] + xp_all[i+1])/2
        xmi_all.append(xmi_calc)

    xi_all = []
    for i in range(0,100,1):
        xi_calc = xmi_all[i] + xni_all[i]
        xi_all.append(xi_calc)
    sic_all = []

    for item in xi_all:
        if item >= 0: 
            sic = item*Ecm
            sic_all.append(sic)    
        else:
            sic = 0
            sic_all.append(sic)

    fic_step = np.multiply(sic_all,a)
    fic = np.divide(fic_step,1000)   
    sis_all = []

    for item in xi_all:
            sis = item*Es
            sis_all.append(sis)           

    fis_step = np.multiply(sis_all,a_s)
    fis = np.divide(fis_step,1000)     

    M_conc = []
    for i in range(0,100):
        multi_c = np.divide(fic,1000)
        M_conc = np.multiply(leverarm,multi_c)

    multi_s = np.divide(fis,1000)
    M_steel = np.multiply(leverarm,multi_s)
    M_sls = sum(M_conc) + sum(M_steel)
    equN = sum(fic) + sum(fis)

    return abs(equN - N)
```

Comment: Sounds like a constrained optimization problem or maybe root finding. Scipy can do either. Can you provide more information?

Comment: Hey kazemakase. Thank you very much for reading my post. I have added more info. I have put the code in a function put im not sure if its correct.

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html

Comment: @omni it might find the x_bot value but can you give me a simple example of how to implement it for My problem.  Thanks In advance

Comment: Can anybody provide a general solution or point me In the right direction please ?